# The best way to spawn objects in both rviz and gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to generate a simulation that automatically executes grasping multiple times to collect success/fail of the specific grasp configuration. Currently, I have robot moveit package (rviz&gazebo), **STL files of objects**, and goal end-effector poses with respect to the **objects' coordinate systems**.

At the moment, my **primary goal** is to spawn an object and a robot simultaneously to use tf (from robot base to object) to define the goal pose of an end-effector for gazebo simulation.

My initial idea of how to setup the simulation is to convert the object STL file to the URDF and load it as part of the robot in both rviz and gazebo. Is there any better idea to achieve the primary goal? I appreciate any comment, suggestion, and information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410679/the-best-way-to-spawn-objects-in-both-rviz-and-gazebo/) by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2022-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will answer my own question here:

I decided to spawn objects only in gazebo to simulate automated object pick up. To do this, I defined a SDF file using STL and import necessary classes from **gazebo_msgs.srv** to spawn and delete objects in the gazebo world. Whoever needs to do the same thing can refer my repository:

https://github.com/kidpaul94/kmr-iiwa-gripkit-cr-plus-l/tree/main/auto_pick/src

---

Originally posted by [kidpaul](https://answers.ros.org/users/72845/kidpaul/) with karma: 38 on 2023-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0